# Save custom form data in shopify customer table

Tags: shopify, custom-data-attribute, shopify-api

I have pet website developed in shopify and I have requirement that create custom form in shopify and store custom form data in shopify default customer table. As shopify do not provide database access so how can I do this ? After insert data I need to display in list view.

[image]

Yes I have tried to create custom form and save custom data in shopify table. Shopify don't provide database access so not able to save custom data. I have temp solution using custom api but is there anything that provided by Shopify ?

Comment: utilize the customer meta-fields to store and list data in Shopify

Answer (score 0):

In Shopify, you would save your customer-specific information in Metafield resources attached to the customer. It is a very nice pattern of use, and as flexible as if you had access to the database table of customers. You use an API call to attach your custom data collected from the form, to the customer. You can make that information available throughout Shopify for business purposes. That is the elegance of API driven Shopify.